# ASP.NET Dropdown list from mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have this code in my `Pageload`

```
string query_regNo = @"SELECT spare_part FROM spare_parts";
cb_description.Items.Clear();
try
{
    conn.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query_regNo, conn);
    MySqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (DR.Read())
    {
        cb_description.Items.Add(new ListItem(DR[0].ToString()));
    }
}
```

and i have this on my `submit button`

```
{
    conn.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query_submit, conn);
    prepareQuery(cmd);
    cmd.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = tf_quantity.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@description"].Value = cb_description.SelectedItem.Value;
    cmd.Parameters["@remarks"].Value = tf_remarks.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@jobID"].Value = job_id != null ? job_id : "1";
    cmd.Parameters["@truck_id"].Value = truck_id;
}
```

and this on my `addquery`

```
private void prepareQuery(MySqlCommand cmd)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@remarks", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@jobID", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@truck_id", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45);
    cmd.Prepare();
}
```

when i click submit button, Only the firstValue(Engine Oil) in my `cb_description` dropdown is being selected, when i select different value, it always add the first value in my spare parts table. How can i get the selected value from my dropdownlist and add it to my  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45);`

i have this on my `aspx`

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="cb_description" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="125px">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: In your `Page_Load` your binding to `DropDown` got check `if (!IsPostBack)` ?

Answer (score 0):

In Page_Load Event put your code in if condition like below.

```
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   string query_regNo = @"SELECT spare_part FROM spare_parts";
   cb_description.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query_regNo, conn);
            MySqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (DR.Read())
            {
                cb_description.Items.Add(new ListItem(DR[0].ToString()));
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Submitting the page means Reloading the page once again. After reloading your dorpdownbox is refreshing.

[Page.IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) Property will solve your problem. If you dont want to refresh the some code then check !Page.IsPostBack